Will cadence care about workflow worker resource?
After read docs, I cannot find about resource related topics.
If I write a CPU/Memory/IO heavy job, how candence can avoid dispatch new job to a high-work load worker?
A example: I will execute a java shell and apply -Xmx4GB JVM, my worker's max memory is 16GB.
Is there already consider design in Candence? How can I define a job's resource requirements to help dispatcher make decisions.

You can specify per worker limit of how many activities can be executed in parallel. Activities are not dispatched to workers without spare slots to process them.

Thanks。 After check your profile, maybe Temporal is a good choice.
